# Ruby replace double blackslash with single blackslash

Tags: ruby

In Ruby I am trying to replace double backslash `\\` with single backslash `\` in string but it's not working.

This is my string

```
line = "this\\is\\line"
```

desired output

```
"this\is\line'
```

This is what i tried

```
line.gsub("\\", "\")  # didn't work
line.gsub("\\", "/\") # didn't work
line.gsub("\\", '\')  # didn't work with single quote as well
line.gsub("\\", '/\') # din't work with single quote as well
```

Comment: The thing the REPL shows when you make a string is *not* the actual contents of the string. It's the printable representation of the contents of the string, which includes escape sequences.

Comment: The string you have stored in `line` already does contain single backslashes. If you do a `puts line`, you will see that it prints just _this\is\line_. Therefore I don't quite understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are being tricked - it actually is working, but the console is displaying it escaped with \ in line. Use `puts` to actually see what it is being set without it being escaped with backslashes.

So #1: `line = "this\\is\\line"` is actually `this\is\line`. Proof:

```
irb(main):015:0> line = "this\\is\\line"
=> "this\\is\\line"
irb(main):016:0> puts line
this\is\line
```

So to actually make a string with double backslashes, you need: `line = "this\\\\is\\\\line"`. Proof:

```
irb(main):017:0> line = "this\\\\is\\\\line"
=> "this\\\\is\\\\line"
irb(main):018:0> puts line
this\\is\\line
```

So finally, once you actually have a string with double backslashes, this is the gsub you want: `line.gsub("\\\\", "\\")`

```
irb(main):020:0> line = "this\\\\is\\\\line"
=> "this\\\\is\\\\line"
irb(main):021:0> puts line.gsub("\\\\", "\\")
this\is\line
```